# DB2 dynamic sql, variables, returning scalar value

Tags: c#, sql, db2

I have a table with:

`ID (int, generated)
    OriginalID (int, nullable)
    ... 
    other columns.`

When inserting a record I would like to set the "OriginalID" to the "ID" that was generated. Currently the script looks like this:

`BEGIN ATOMIC
     DECLARE i INT;
     SET i = SELECT ID FROM NEW TABLE(INSERT INTO MyTable(...) VALUES (....));
     UPDATE MyTable SET ORIGINALID=i WHERE ID=i;
    END`

now the problem I have is how to return the "i", to get the value in code, when calling ExecuteScalar method?

I have already tried "SELECT i FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1", "VALUES (i)" - both statements return a "null" in code.

I do get the value if I call ExecuteScalar with script like this: 
`SELECT ID FROM NEW TABLE(INSERT INTO MyTable(...) VALUES (....));`

The query is executed from c# code (.net core/IBM.Data.DB2.Core 1.2.2.100) by using a DB2Connection and DB2Command:

```
var query = ...;
var connection = new DB2Connection(conn_string);
var command = new DB2Command(connection, query);
command.parameters.Add(...);
var returnValue = command.ExecuteScalar(); << the value here is always 
null if trying to return the db2 variable; it works only if executing 
"single statement"
```

**** edit ****

Got it working with help of Mark Barinstein:

last statement in query is now: "set @newId = i;" and in code:

```
var newId = new DB2Parameter("@newId", DB2Type.Integer);
newId.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(newId);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
var id = newId.Value;
```

Comment: Why don't you use an `AFTER INSERT` for-each-row trigger to set `ORIGINALID`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with c#, but you may try some jdbc CallableStatement analogue with `BEGIN ...; set ? = i; END` (not `BEGIN ATOMIC ... END`) and registering an `out` parameter as for a stored procedure. This works with jdbc.

Comment: Mark: It's a part of versioning system (even when updating data, we make a new row ), so sometimes the originalid is inserted with a specific value pointing to the original/initial id. I'll try what you suggest first thing in morning when in office, thanks!